# Regular expression to check strings containing a set of words separated by a delimiter

Tags: regex

As the title says, I'm trying to build up a regular expression that can recognize strings with this format:

```
word!!cat!!DOG!! ... Phone!!home!!
```

where `!!` is used as a delimiter. Each word must have a length between 1 and 5 characters. Empty words are not allowed, i.e. no strings like `!!`,`!!!!` etc.

A word can only contain alphabetical characters between `a` and `z` (case insensitive). After each word I expect to find the special delimiter `!!`.

I came up with the solution below but since I need to add other controls (e.g. words can contain spaces) I would like to know if I'm on the right way.

```
(([a-zA-Z]{1,5})([!]{2}))+
```

Also note that empty strings are not allowed, hence the use of `+`

Help and advices are very welcome since I just started learning how to build regular expressions. I run some tests using http://regexr.com/ and it seems to be okay but I want to be sure. Thank you!

Examples that shouldn't match:

```
a!!b!!aaaaaa!!
a123!!b!!c!!
aAaa!!bbb
aAaa!!bbb!
```

Comment: what that should match?

Comment: it sounds OK to me :)

Comment: If you add anchors to the regular expression that you provided, then it works -> https://regex101.com/r/DNoEYf/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Splitting the string and using the values between the `!!`

It depends on what you want to do with the regular expression. If you want to match the values between the `!!`, here are two ways:

#### Matching with groups

```
([^!]+)!!
```

- `[^!]+` requires at least 1 character other than `!`
- `!!` instead of `[!]{2}` because it is the same but much more readable

#### Matching with lookahead

If you only want to match the actual word (and not the two `!`), you can do this by using a **positive lookahead**:

```
[^!]+(?=!!)
```

- `(?=)` is a positive lookahead. It requires everything inside, i.e. here `!!`, to be directly after the previous match. It however won't be in the resulting match.

*Here is a [live example](https://regex101.com/r/9iBTbJ/1).*

---

### Validating the string

If you however want to check the **validity** of the whole string, then you need something like this:

```
^([^!]+!!)+$
```

- `^` start of the string
- `$` end of the string
- It requires the whole string to contain only `([^!]+!!)` one or more than one times.

---

***If `[^!]` does not fit your requirements, you can of course replace it with `[a-zA-Z]` or similar.***

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer is very detailed and informative!